# Ignore gradle transitive project dependencies using eclipse WTP

Tags: java, eclipse, build, gradle, eclipse-wtp

I have a war project (project A) that has a compile dependency on another project that contains shared libraries (project B), however I don't want the transitive dependencies of the project B to be included on the WTP deployment.

When I generate the war file using gradle the transitive dependencies from Project B are ignored as I want to, however WTP keeps copying all libs into the /WEB-INF/lib directory and therefore I have classloader issues.

I have tried to to ignore transitive dependencies from Project B using `transitive = false` and ignoring specific dependencies with `exclude` both at dependency and configuration level with not success so far and I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

My configuration is as follows:

**Project A**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { // ext release
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/ext-release-local"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
    maven { // libs release
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-release-local"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
    maven { // libs snapshot
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-snapshot-local"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
    maven { // SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases
        url "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release" }
    maven { // SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases
        url "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external" }
    maven { // SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Library Releases
        url "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release" }
    maven { // SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Library Releases
        url "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external" }
}

group = 'com.thisproject'

sourceCompatibility = '1.6'

version = '1.6'

war {
    baseName = 'ROOT'
    archiveName = baseName+'.'+extension
    destinationDir = file('build/')
}

task deployToFolder(dependsOn: 'war') << {
    copy {
        from war.archivePath
        into "${deployFolder}"
    }
}

task jenkinsTest{
    inputs.files test.outputs.files
    doLast{
        def timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
        test.testResultsDir.eachFile { it.lastModified = timestamp }
    }
}

build.dependsOn(jenkinsTest)

configurations {
    runtime.exclude group: 'commons-validator', module: 'commons-validator'
    runtime {
        transitive = false
    }
}

dependencies{
    providedCompile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.16'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'org.springframework.security.web', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework.social', name: 'spring-social-web', version: '1.0.2.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework.social', name: 'spring-social-core', version: '1.0.2.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework.social', name: 'spring-social-facebook', version: '1.0.1.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework.social', name: 'spring-social-twitter', version: '1.0.2.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'spring-social-google', name: 'spring-social-google', version: '1.0'
    providedCompile group: 'jstl', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework.security', name:'org.springframework.security.taglibs', version:'3.1.1.RELEASE'

    compile(project(':projectB')) {
        exclude module:'commons-validator'
            transitive = false
    }

    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '2.5'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jsp-api', version: '2.0'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'org.springframework.transaction', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.2.0'
    providedCompile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.4'

    providedCompile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '1.0.0.GA'
    providedCompile 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0.2'
    providedCompile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.10.Final'
}

eclipse {
    project { natures 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.nature' }
    wtp {
        component { deployName = 'ROOT' }
        facet {
            facet name: 'jst.web', version: '2.5'
            facet name: 'jst.java', version: '1.6'
        }
    }
}

compileJava { 
  options.encoding = "UTF-8" 
}
```

**Project B**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { // ext release
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/ext-release-local"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
    maven { // libs release
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-release-local"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
    maven { // libs snapshot
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-snapshot-local"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
    maven { // SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases
        url "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release"
    }
    maven { // SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases
        url "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external"
    }
    maven { // SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Library Releases
        url "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release"
    }
    maven { // SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Library Releases
        url "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external"
    }
}

group = 'com.thisproject'

sourceCompatibility = '1.6'

version = '1.7.26-SNAPSHOT'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart', 'Implementation-Version': version
    }
    destinationDir = file('build/')
}

task deployToFolder(dependsOn: 'jar') << {
    copy {
        from jar.archivePath
        into "${deployFolder}"
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

dependencies{
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.16'
    compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.lowagie', name: 'itext', version: '2.0.8'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.6'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.4'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.4'
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.2.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.axis', name: 'axis-jaxrpc', version: '1.4'
    compile group: 'com.esendex', name: 'esendex.sdk', version: '1.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-core', version: '1.9.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-snowball', version: '1.9.1'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-client', version: '1.12'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-json', version: '1.12'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey.ri', name: 'jax-rs-ri', version: '1.12'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version: '1.9.2'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.10.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '4.3.1.Final'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'org.springframework.aop', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'org.springframework.beans', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'org.springframework.context', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'org.springframework.jdbc', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'org.springframework.orm', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'org.springframework.oxm', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'org.springframework.transaction', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'org.springframework.web.servlet', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'spring-social-jpa', name: 'spring-social-jpa', version: '0.0.1'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jsr173_api', version: '1.0'
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '1.0.0.GA'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber', name: 'libphonenumber', version: '4.1'
    compile group: 'axis', name: 'axis', version: '1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-email', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'catalina', version: '6.0.35'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jsp-api', version: '2.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'org.springframework.security.web', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'commons-httpclient', name: 'commons-httpclient', version: '3.0.1'
    compile group: 'net.sf.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '2.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'org.springframework.test', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    testCompile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.10.Final'
    testCompile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '3.6.10.Final'
    testCompile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.3.1.Final'

    compile(group: 'com.paypal.sdk', name: 'merchantsdk', version: '2.2.98')
    compile(group: 'com.paypal.sdk', name: 'paypal-core', version: '1.1.1')
}

compileJava { 
  options.encoding = "UTF-8" 
}
```

Comment: Have you had any progress on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I changed to Intellij shortly after this, only to find that Intellij had other problems also related to this. I then figured out how to solve it with Intellij and I left Eclipse aside. Good luck

Comment: I ended up hacking into the process of generating XML files. For now seems to be working but it's a pain.

Comment: You might want to elaborate your solution and maybe add some code into a response, it might help others and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a massive search through net and digging into so many Gradle and WTP stuff, I was able to get this working. Basically, there are three ways to ignore dependencies in WTP deploy directory (or I am aware of only three of them!).

**1. Setting transitive to false**
As you have mentioned in the question and the syntax is like:

```
compile('group.id:jar.name:1.0') {transitive = false}
runtime('group.id:jar.name:1.0') {transitive = false}
```

This should prevent the dependant JARs of being added to final WTP directory.

**2. Excluding using provided syntax**
Gadle comes with a feature to prevent dependencies of being added to final WAR file which in here can be used to prevent them of being copied to WTP deploy dir. And here is the syntax:

```
providedCompile 'group.id:jar.name:1.0'
providedRuntime 'group.id:jar.name:1.0'
```

**3. HACK!!**
Here comes the most interesting part. What if none of the above works? I found [this](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3405) thread on STS jira which is about same issue and that pointed me to [this](https://github.com/thatguy1177/gradleWtpExample/tree/firstWorkingFix) solution which did not work for me but gave me a clue to do my own hack as follow. In the build script I added following code to ignore the dependencies manually:

```
subprojects { 
    project.afterEvaluate {
        eclipse.classpath.file.withXml {
            it.asNode().'classpathentry'.each { entry ->
                def path = entry.@path.toLowerCase()
                if (path.contains('your-jar-to-ignore')) {
                    entry.attributes.each { attr ->
                        if (attr.attribute.@name.contains('org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency')) {
                            entry.remove(attr)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It hacks into the process of generating `.classpath` file (which is done by gradle) and prevents it of adding dependency attribute to the specified JAR. This way it doesn't get copied to WTP deploy directory.
Hope this helps people who land on this page, but I really think either Eclipse or Gradle people should fix this issue as it is very frustrating.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I'll give that hack a try, it looks promissing