# Issues excluding transitive dependency of project reference from eclipse class path

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, dependency-management, gradle-eclipse

I have several gradle projects in my eclipse workspace.  For the sake of simplicity I'm only really interested in 2 of them, let's just use A and B for this.

So the problem I'm having is that Project A has an included dependency on JBoss, which pulls in javax validation-api 1.0.0.GA, and Project B has a dependency on javax validation-api 1.1.0.Final.  Since Gradle itself resolves the conflict by using the newer library first, B is happy when built by gradle.  But Eclipse itself includes errors which are very distracting while editing.

The correct version of the validation-api jar ends up in B's class path but the problem is that the Gradle IDE plugin changes the project(':A') dependency to a project reference, and Eclipse seems to give the project reference precedence over the external jar.  So the old jar is preferred by extension.

I tried adding `{ exclude module: 'validation-api' }` in B's build.gradle for the dependency on A which works according to the output of 'gradle dependencies', however since Eclipse just gets as far as making it a project reference, it won't exclude the jar and the problem remains.

Also per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720565/ignore-gradle-transitive-project-dependencies-using-eclipse-wtp) I tried adding `{ transitive = false }` and the same thing happens.  I don't think even the hack posed there would work for me since the .classpath contains a single reference to the Gradle container so there's nothing to remove.

I've managed to get around this by explicitly including a reference to the correct version of the jar from my gradle cache and then moving it above the Gradle Classpath Container so that eclipse sees that version first.

My question is:  Is there a better/more generic way to do this?  Preferably one that I can commit to source control without breaking other people's builds or requiring them to manually modify paths or properties somewhere?  There is another project with what appears to be a similar issue so something I can fix in the build.gradle file would be awesome.

Worst case scenario, I could probably switch to IntelliJ if that behaves itself better than the Eclipse-Gradle integration?

Answer (score 2):

These kind of transitive dependency issues are long-standing problem with Gradle Eclipse integration (both in STS tooling and also commandline generated .classpath metadata from Gradle's Eclipse plugin. The problem is the way that Eclipse computes transitive classpaths.

Only recently we found a reasonable solution to this problem. Actually there are now two solutions, one better than the other but depending on your situation you might want to use either of them.

**The first** solution is a bug fix that changes the classpath order of project dependencies so that they are no longer 'preferred' over jar dependencies [PR-74](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/pull/74). To get this fix you may need to install gradle tooling from a snapshot update site because the fix went in after 3.6.3.

This solution doesn't fix the real problem (you still have the 'wrong' stuff on the classpath) but just makes it less likely to cause real problem in your projects.

**The second** solution is to enable use of the 'Custom Tooling API model' [PR-55](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/pull/55) introduced in STS 3.6.3. This is a bit experimental and only works for recent version of Gradle, at least 1.12 but probably better to use 2.x. It also only works for projects that have 'Dependency management' enabled (if not enabled you are using the .classpath generated by Gradle's eclipse plugin which has the same 'broken' classpath issues as the STS tooling).

The 'custom tooling model' is really the better solution in principle as it fixes the way gradle classpath get mapped to eclipse projects so that project dependencies are no longer exported and each project gets its own classpath considering dependencies conflict resolution.

To enable this go to "Window >> Preferences >> Gradle" and enable checkbox "Use Custom Tooling Model".

Comment: Using the Custom Tooling API did the trick to me! It is a shame that in a multi-project setup takes so much time to process all the models...